# broken refreshed image when move crosshair on an imageview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm try to implement a crosshair item on a imageview using pyqtgraph, it seems ok with the functions.
But, when I zoom in the image and move the crosshair, there are some broken points or lines on the boundary of pixel.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

completed code as below, could be run and replicate the problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This example demonstrates the use of ImageView, which is a high-level widget for 
displaying and analyzing 2D and 3D data. ImageView provides:

  1. A zoomable region (ViewBox) for displaying the image
  2. A combination histogram and gradient editor (HistogramLUTItem) for
     controlling the visual appearance of the image
  3. A timeline for selecting the currently displayed frame (for 3D data only).
  4. Tools for very basic analysis of image data (see ROI and Norm buttons)

"""
## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)
#import initExample

import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# Interpret image data as row-major instead of col-major
pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with ImageView widget
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(800,800)
plt=pg.PlotItem()
imv = pg.ImageView(view=plt)
label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
plt.addItem(label)
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageView')

## Create random 3D data set with noisy signals
img = pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.normal(size=(200, 200)), (5, 5)) * 20 + 100
img = img[np.newaxis,:,:]
decay = np.exp(-np.linspace(0,0.3,100))[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
data = np.random.normal(size=(100, 200, 200))
data += img * decay
data += 2

## Add time-varying signal
sig = np.zeros(data.shape[0])
sig[30:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 70))
sig[40:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 60))
sig[70:] += np.exp(-np.linspace(1,10, 30))

sig = sig[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * 3
data[:,50:60,30:40] += sig


## Display the data and assign each frame a time value from 1.0 to 3.0
imv.setImage(data, xvals=np.linspace(1., 3., data.shape[0]))

## Set a custom color map
colors = [
    (0, 0, 0),
    (45, 5, 61),
    (84, 42, 55),
    (150, 87, 60),
    (208, 171, 141),
    (255, 255, 255)
]
cmap = pg.ColorMap(pos=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), color=colors)
imv.setColorMap(cmap)

#cross hair
vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
plt.addItem(vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
plt.addItem(hLine, ignoreBounds=True)


vb = plt.vb

def mouseMoved(evt):
    pos = evt[0]  ## using signal proxy turns original arguments into a tuple
    if plt.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
        mousePoint = vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
#        index = int(mousePoint.x())
#        if index > 0 and index < len(data):
#            label.setText("<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x=%0.1f,   <span style='color: red'>y1=%0.1f</span>" % (mousePoint.x(), data[index, index]))
        vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
        hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())

proxy = pg.SignalProxy(plt.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseMoved)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

I expect the image should be good at anytime, when I move the crosshair.

Thank you.